# Does the reaction force of the surface applied when an object breaks it (the surface)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Imagine there is a table. then put a very heavy object, that breaks the surface. does the table react as much as the force that the object's given to it or it doesn't? how is it?

Answer (score 1):

It reacts with as much force as it's given until it can no longer bear the weight and eventually breaks.